# Angular display Filtering Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When a user selects a tag, I want to display only the blogs containing that tag.
For example when a user selects the '#C#' tag only posts with this tag will be displayed.

My set up is as follows: I have an array of blogs which contain post tags which contain tags:

```
 export interface IBlog
{
    id: number
    title: string
    content: string
    subscription: number
    time: string
    created: Date;
    imageUrl: string
    coverImage: string
    image: string
    likes: number
    body: string
    comments?:{
        message: string
        handle: string,
        city: string,
        country: string
    },
    articleLinkUrl?: string,
    sessions: ISession[],
    mainComments: IComments[],
    postTags: IPostTags[]
}

export interface ISession
{
    id: number,
    name: string,
    presenter: string,
    duration: number,
    level: string,
    abstract: string,
    voters: string[]
}

export interface IComments
{
    id: number,
    message: string   
}
export interface IPostTags
{
    id: number,
    tag: ITag[]   
}
export interface ITag
{
    id: number,
    name: string   
}
```

I have a blog-list.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import { BlogService} from './shared/blog.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { IBlog } from './shared';


@Component({

    template: `
    <div>
    <h1>Upcoming Blogs</h1>
    <hr/>  

    <div class= "btn-group btn-group-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-default" [class.active] = "filterBy==='all'" (click) = "filterBy='all'">All</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" [class.active] = "filterBy==='c#'" (click) = "filterBy='#C#'">C#</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" [class.active] = "filterBy==='angular'" (click) = "filterBy='#Angular'">Angular</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" [class.active] = "filterBy==='netcore'" (click) = "filterBy='#NetCore'">.NET Core</button>
    </div>

        <div class ="row">                     
                <blog-thumbnail  [filterBy]="filterBy" [blogs] = "blogs"></blog-thumbnail>
               
            <div class='row' style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h3 style="margin:0">Sort by Tag</h3>
            </div> 
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class= "btn-group btn-group-sm" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" [class.active] = "sortBy==='name'" (click) = "sortBy='name'">By Name</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" [class.active] = "sortBy==='votes'" (click) = "sortBy='votes'">By Votes</button>
                </div>               
        </div>        
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
})

export class BlogListComponent implements OnInit{
    blogs:IBlog[]
    filterBy: string = 'all';
    
    constructor(private blogService: BlogService, private route: ActivatedRoute){       
    }

ngOnInit(){
   this.blogs = this.route.snapshot.data['blogs']
}
}
```

This displays a blog-thumbnail component

```
import {Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output, OnChanges} from '@angular/core'
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
import { IBlog, IPostTags } from './shared';

@Component ({
    selector: 'blog-thumbnail',
    template: `
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let blog of blogsSession">
    <div [routerLink] = "['/blogs', blog.id]" class="well hoverwell thumbnail">
    <img src={{blog?.coverImage}}/>
    <h2>{{blog?.title | uppercase}}</h2>   
    <div>{{blog?.created | date}}</div>
    <div>Content: {{blog?.content}}</div>
    <div>Tags: {{blog?.content}}</div>
    <div well-title *ngIf="blog?.mainComments">
          {{blog?.likes}} Reactions
          <i *ngIf="blog?.likes >= 1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" style="color:red"></i>
          {{blog.mainComments.length}} Comments
          <i *ngIf="blog.mainComments.length >= 1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" ></i>
    </div>  

    <div well-title *ngIf="blog?.postTags">
         
          {{blog.postTags.length}} Post Tags
          <i *ngIf="blog.postTags.length >= 1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" ></i>
    </div>  

    </div>
    `,
    styles:[
        `
        .thumbnail {min-height: 210px;}
        .pad-left {margin-left: 10px;}
        .well div { color: #bbb;}
        
        `]
})

export class BlogThumbnailComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() blog: IBlog
    @Input() filterBy: string;
    @Input() blogs: IBlog[];
    blogsSession: IBlog[] = [];


    
    getStartTimeStyle(): any{
        if (this.blog && this.blog.time === '7:30pm')       
        return{color: '#003300', 'font-weight' : 'bold'}
        return{};

    }

    ngOnChanges(){
        if(this.blogs){
            this.filterSessions(this.filterBy);
            //this.sortBy === 'name' ? null : null;
        }   
    }
    
    filterSessions(filter){
        if(filter === 'all'){
            this.blogsSession= this.blogs.slice(0);
        }
            else
            {        

                 
                this.blogsSession = this.blogs.filter(blog => {               
                         return blog.postTags.filter( postTag =>{
                            postTag.tag.name === filter
                         })
                        })
this commented out code works but it is not what i want 
                // this.blogsSession = this.blogs.filter(blog => {               
                //     return blog.postTags.length < 2;                                                         
                //})
            }             
                   
            }   
        }
```

The following section off code is where I am having my problem. It does not work:

```
     this.blogsSession = this.blogs.filter(blog => {               
                                 return blog.postTags.filter( postTag =>{
                                    postTag.tag.name === filter
})
                            })
```

I have spent a large amount of time on this. Would anybody be able to explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function used in the `filter()` method should return `true` or `false` (or actually a value that coerces to true or false). Your function returns an array; you are filtering `blog.postTags`.

Try this instead:

```
this.blogsSession = this.blogs.filter(blog => {               
    return blog.postTags.some(postTag => postTag.tag.name === filter)
})
```

The `some()` method will return `true` if at least one of the items in the array meet the conditions used in the function.

Comment: The inner `some` method currently does not return anything - you need to change `postTag => { postTag.tag.name === filter }` to not use `{}` (`postTag => postTag.tag.name === filter`) or add a return statement (`postTag => { return postTag.tag.name === filter; }`).

Comment: @pascalpuetz You are right. I was a bit hasty with posting my comment. I will edit it. Tnx for noticing.

Comment: Hi Muijs. I will now edit my reply. That does work. Brilliant thanks guys. I was totally stomped by that

Answer (score -1):

Why do you have 2 filter operators? I think this:

```
  this.blogsSession = this.blogs.filterpostTags.filter( postTag =>{
                                    postTag.tag.name.toLocaleLowerCase() === filter.toLocaleLowerCase()
})
```

should be enough.